# Global resources in Puppet

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to add a global resource?

I have about 1000 nodes with different configurations and now I want to install a package on every single node.  Can it be done in `site.pp`?

I have a default node, but from what I can tell it is only for unrecognised nodes so I don't think this is the way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the way you have written your puppet manifests. If you have a class included on every node, then you could add the definition to that.

You could user hiera to allow you to customise the default packages on a per machine basis. If you had a module called `siteconfig`, then you could could create a class something like;

### modules/siteconfig/manifests/init.pp

```
class siteconfig {
  include siteconfig::defaults

  package{$::siteconfig::params::packages:
    ensure => 'present',
  }
}
```

### modules/siteconfig/manifests/params.pp

```
class siteconfig::params( 
  $packages = []
) {
  validate_array($packages)
}
```

and then define `siteconfig::params::packages` in hiera as an array of packages to be installed by default. This means that you could easily add more default packages by editing the array in hiera, and you could customise it on a per-host basis.

Bonus points if you work out how to use `create_resources` instead!